# How to wait until a certain output (string) occurs while executing subprocess.check_output?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess

I am trying to write a Python script which will download my software build. So the script will wait until certain output occurs and proceed for the next task:

```
import os
import subprocess

out = subprocess.check_output(["wget", "--downloadlink--"])
print(out)
if "saved" in out:
    print("Download completed!!")
```

It's not printing any output. It's simply executing the command and exiting.

I tried the above program but didn't get any desired result. Any other way of doing it?

Comment: Did you consider there is no `saved` in the output?

Comment: My output from manual execution "2022-12-18 01:08:24 (32.0 MB/s) - ‘XXXXXXXXX’ saved [6363373673/6363373673].Even I am not able to print the output.

Comment: Did you try adding `shell=True` to the `check_output`?

Comment: After adding shell=True,Got the error
wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  wget: missing URL
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
returned non-zero exit status 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module) way is to use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).
However if it's not available.
The key point is to tell the method to output `STDERR` to get access to the message.

```py
import subprocess

out = subprocess.check_output(
    [
        "wget",
        "--downloadlink--",
    ],
   stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
)

if "saved" in str(out, "utf-8"):
    print("saved !!")
# saved !!
```

*Note: I don't think is the right way to check if the download of a file is OK. This approach is weak because it's rely on a text string in the output. It should be better to use at least the return code of `wget` or even better performing the download directly through a Python lib. However I do not know your constraints.*

Comment: Thank You for the response!!But in my Linux python version,subprocess.run is not there!!!

Comment: @sbehera Updated with `check_output` I think the key point is to output `STDERR`

Comment: It worked indeed.Does it wait until execution get over or how it is?

Comment: I tried a wrong URL but it didnt show the error output.

Comment: If an error occurs it raises a `subprocess.CalledProcessError` so you have to catch and manage it. As I said in the note, I'm not sure is the best way to manage file download from Python.